# Running HIVE queries directly from S3 input files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I am using Interative Hive Session in Elastice Map Reduce to run Hive. Previously I was loading data from S3 into Hive tables.Now, I want to run some scripts on S3 input files without loading data into Hive Tables.

Is this possible?If yes then how can this be achieved?

Comment: For this type of "queries" you can use Pig or plain MapReduce jobs

Comment: @guy Thanks Ya I figured it out there is no way this can be achieved.I tried copying the data into tables but it showed null values. Probably I was to clean the data and then load it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can run queries on data right in S3.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydata (key STRING, value INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3n://mys3bucket/';
```

or similar